# VBA - How to handle the data validation error?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a protected workbook. It works perfectly fine. Until we counter the below error.

Data validation is used on one of the cells, where the user is not allowed to enter a date before 01/01/1970 and it throws an error when we do so.

But the concern is when we click on "Retry or cancel". I get runtime error which is causing the problem. Once we encounter the error it affects other fields with VBA enabled(VBA on other fields will not work until we close and open a fresh spreadsheet). How do we handle such error?
Please suggest

[image: Data Validation]

[image: Message Prompt]

[image: Runtime error]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim myValue
        With Application
            myValue = Target.Formula
            .Undo
            Target.Formula = myValue
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E43")) Is Nothing Then
            With Range("E44")
                If Target.Value = "Specific Number of Days" Then
                    .Locked = False
                    .Activate
                Else
                    'This handles **ANY** other value in the dropdown
                    .Locked = True
                    '.Clear
                End If
            End With
            ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E30")) Is Nothing Then
                If Target.Value = "YES" Then Call Notify Else Call NotifyUser
            ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E31")) Is Nothing Then
                If Target.Value = "YES" Then Call Delta Else Call DeltaUser
        End If
       Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any VBA code running in the background? Seems like it might be a `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` or `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` segment conflicting with it

Comment: Your VBA code is not capturing the error from cancel or the code for retry.

Comment: In the VBA editor if under general options you change the error handling so that it says "break in class module" then when you see that error you should have the "debug" option enabled, so you can see the line throwing the error. See: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx

Comment: @Maldred Yes, I do have `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`. How do I overcome the conflict?

Comment: @sady can you post the code? I can't tell unless we see what's going on. Also, follow mooseman's instructions to isolate the error

Comment: @mooseman Sure, checking on that.

Comment: also, without seeing the code, try looking at the `.validation` of `Target`

Comment: @JohnColeman  Thanks, let me go to the page you have suggested.

Comment: @Maldred I have updated the code in my question for your reference.

Comment: There error here is at `.Undo`, are you just trying to prevent the user from inputting a formula here? Ie. `=Today()`